# Centering StackPanel in a Grid UWP

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

For my Universal Windows App, I am trying to center a StackPanel in a Grid on Page like in the Picture. But when I run the code below, three buttons are placed centered at the bottom. What could be the problem?

[image]

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page>
    <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 0">
                <Button x:Name="BackButton" Height="50" Width="150" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="White">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Viewbox MaxHeight="50" MaxWidth="50">
                            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Back" Foreground="White"></SymbolIcon>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold">Back</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Width="150" Height="50" Content="Page 1" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Button Width="150" Height="50" Content="Page 2" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Button Width="150" Height="50" Content="Page 3" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Width="150" Height="5" Background="#FFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="240" />
        </Grid>
        <Frame
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="Frame">
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Page1.xaml

```
<Page>
    <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Height="150" Width="300" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Padding="0">Page 1</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Height="150" Width="300" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Padding="0">Page 2</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Height="150" Width="300" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Padding="0">Page 3</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Edit**:
the solution is:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Delete `VerticalAlignment="Top"` in Grid

Comment: If you have solved your issue, please post your answer below, please avoid post the answer in your question.

Comment: Actually, you just have to switch the row definitions in the top most Grid. First with Height=Auto, second *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is  setting a reasonable row height ratio. And remove `VerticalAlignment="Top"` from `Grid` where placed in Row 0 area.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

**Update**

For your requirement, you have no need set a custom navigation bar in the top area. You could use `NavigationView` to approach. The latest Navigation provide
Top display mode. 
[image]

```
<NavigationView x:Name="nvSample" Header="This is Header Text" PaneDisplayMode="Top">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem  Content="Menu Item1" Tag="SamplePage1" />
        <NavigationViewItem  Content="Menu Item2" Tag="SamplePage2" />
        <NavigationViewItem  Content="Menu Item3" Tag="SamplePage3" />
        <NavigationViewItem  Content="Menu Item4" Tag="SamplePage4" />
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
</NavigationView>
```

For more please refer `NavigationView` [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview).

Comment: I don't think setting height to 0.1* (relative value) is a good idea. it should be either absolute value, or auto, because height of header does not depend of parent (window) height

Comment: @Liero,Yep, but op give his solution, I just help move to the below. For his requirement, the better way is makeing a NavigationView in the top area and place the Frame below.